# git svn - error under cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin

I have cygwin and git. I'm trying to commit with git to svn - `git svn dcommit`. But it fails with strange error:

```
$ git svn dcommit
      4 [main] perl 5536 C:\cygwin\bin\perl.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\perl5\5.10\i686-cygwin\auto\List\Util\Util.dll to same address as parent: 0xA20000 != 0xB40000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0088B508  6102749B  (0088B508, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0088B7F8  6102749B  (61177B80, 00008000, 00000000, 61179977)
0088C828  61004AFB  (611A136C, 6125AB3C, 00A20000, 00B40000)
End of stack trace
```

How can I fix it ? Thanks.

**P.S.**
My system is windows 7 64 bit.

**Update**

`reabase` helped. but I had to reboot after executing rebase.

Comment: I came here due to the original problem, but any command I run from inside ash also results in an error: `[main] ash 7152 fork: child 1920 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you try a **[`rebaseall`](https://superuser.com/questions/231590/running-rebaseall-on-cygwin)** like [described here](http://yosanai.com/cygwin-unable-remap-dll-same-address-parent)?

> When you are working with Cygwin, sometimes you will get an error like this

```
unable to remap some.dll to same address as parent someapp 4292 fork:
child 3964 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11"
```

> Then you would need to run rebaseall.
>   In order to run it, close all your Cygwin windows, Execute `<cygwin_home>\bin\ash.exe`. It will open a new console window.
>   Execute `rebaseall` there.
>   Once it has completed, you can go back to running Cygwin again without any issues :-)

---

The OP [gor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496825/gor) reports he had to reboot to make `rebaseall` work.
[Dan Moulding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95706/dan-moulding) mentions in the comments:

> I'll just add that closing all Cygwin windows may not be sufficient.
>   **You should make sure all Cygwin processes and services are terminated and/or stopped** (`ps -a` from `ash` should show nothing but `ash` and `ps`) **before rebasing**.

---

[rsenna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158074/rsenna) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014554/git-svn-error-under-cygwin/5014721#comment32772351_5014721):

> For an explanation of why this is needed, see [`fatal error - unable to remap to same address as parent`: Cygwin, Ruby on Rails, System calls](http://www.mylifestartingup.com/2009/04/fatal-error-unable-to-remap-to-same.html)
>
> So what actually is happening?
>   Well, in this case, the problem was a result of the way Windows manages its `.dll`'s.
>
> Windows uses **`ASLR`** (address space layout randomization) to manage its `.dll`'s. It loads your dll's into different areas of memory every time you boot your computer.
>   If this gets out of whack then the next time you look for that `.dll` - you can crash your system. Or if you look in the wrong place, you can crash your system.
>   So how can this system get out of whack? Well, running your cygwin setup program can affect record keeping, especially if the `ASLR` has changed but Cygwin is holding on to an older copy (this can happen when setup doesn't complete).
>
> ASLR is a great defense against malware or hackers. Hackers can't constantly try new addresses for your `.dll`'s without crashing your system.

Comment: No effect. I'v closed all cygwin windows, ran `c:\cygwin\bin\ash`, `\bin\rabaseall`, `exit`. Then started cygwin and got the same error

Comment: @gor: well, it was worth a shot.

Comment: @gor: only if some processes (close to the Windows kernel) need to be stopped and restarted.

Comment: @VonC strange, but after reboot it works. wondering, will it stop working after week or two ?

Comment: @gor: it shouldn't stop working, unless (maybe) if you made massive changes in the cygwin configuration, like installation lots of new components or updating only partially your existing configuration)

Comment: I'll just add that closing all Cygwin windows may not be sufficient. You should make sure all Cygwin processes and services are terminated and/or stopped (`ps -a` from ash should show nothing but `ash` and `ps`) before rebasing.

Comment: +1 Worked for me. For an explanation of why this is needed, see http://www.mylifestartingup.com/2009/04/fatal-error-unable-to-remap-to-same.html

Comment: @rsenna interesting. I have added a relevant extract of that blog post in the answer.

Comment: The same happens for me in the git console (win 8). However, it's not a full cygwin setup. I can't find any ash.exe. Any ideas on how to deal with this case?

Comment: @Meglio not on the to of my head, 4 years later. That might be a good base for a separate question, with a detailed description of your setup.

Answer (score 13):

I was having this issue but running rebaseall wouldn't fix the problem.  I was attempting to run git svn dcommit and seeing the remap errors mentioned no matter how many times I ran rebaseall and/or rebooted.

Here's a sample of what I saw.  Note the reference to address **0x6FA00000**

> $ git svn dcommit Committing to
>       844 [main] perl 1136 C:\cygwin\bin\perl.exe: *** fatal
>   error - unable to remap
>   C:\cygwin\bin\cygdb-4.5.dll to same
>   address as parent: 0x58B40000 !=
>   **0x6FA00000** Stack trace: Frame
>   Function  Args 0082B458  6102792B 
>   (0082B458, 00000000, 00000000,
>   00000000) 0082B748  6102792B 
>   (6117DC60, 00008000, 00000000,
>   6117F977) 0082C778  61004F3B 
>   (611A6FAC, 61247BCC, 58B40000,
>   6FA00000) End of stack trace
>         3 [main] perl 4680 fork: child 1136 - died waiting for dll loading,
>   errno 11

I don't think it's important but I'm running on Windows7 Enterprise 32 bit using my company's corporate image.

I was able to fix this following the advice I found on the Chromium wiki:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/CygwinDllRemappingFailure

I used ListDlls.exe (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx) from cygwin to capture output of DLLs loaded in running processes and grep'ed for the address causing issues:

> $ ./ListDlls.exe | tee foo
>   $ cat foo | grep 6fa000
>
> ...
>
> 0x6fa00000  0x3c000   9.05.0005.9574  C:\PROGRA~1\Sophos\SOPHOS~1\SOPHOS~1.DLL

This matched load address of a DLL provided by Sophos Security which my IT group has running on our machines by default and was the cause of the failure.  rebaseall didn't have a chance to fix the problem because the Sophos provided DLL isn't part of cygwin.

The Chromium wiki said to choose a base address less than the DLL causing the issue so I picked **0x60000000**.  You may have to pick a different base address depending on the offending DLL you might see.

I reran rebaseall from a cmd.exe prompt and no other cygwin processes running.

> c:\cygwin\bin>ash /usr/bin/rebaseall
>   -b 0x60000000

After restarting my cygwin shell git svn dcommit worked.

Comment: THANK YOU!!  These errors had been off-and-on before today, but just started biting me in a way that no amount of rebasing would fix.

Answer (score 4):

Faced similar problems and it didnt go awway till i ran 
1. rebaseall
2. perlrebase
3. peflagsall

run them all to fix the problem

Comment: I wish this answer was higher up, because the perlrebase was key for me.  I believe git still has a bunch of perl scripts.

Comment: Joel's answer led me to perl as the problem. The perlrebase solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers didn't result in a reliable fix to the problem of running cygwin git on 64bit Windows (Windows 7) for our team. I posted a question on the git mailing this and got this response from Pascal Obry:

> Jon,
>
> This is a known issue. I have since a long time left Windows world but
>   I still have some notes to "fix" this:
>
> > From the ash shell (be sure that no Cygwin process are still running):
>
> $ rebaseall
>
> $ peflagsall
>
> Try your command again. If it still doesn't work, try instead: $
>   rebaseall -b 0x50000000 -o 0x80000 or -b 0xNNNN0000 where NNNN is any
>   hex number between 2000 and 7000. The -o option tell to leave more
>   space between the dlls, it may also help. It did in my case.
>
> If you are curious, look at /usr/share/doc/Cygwin/rebase-3.0.README
>   for more explanation.

See also: http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg183753.html

Pascal also noted in a followup that:

> ... the most important part is running peflagsall, this was the way to
>   fix that properly on Win7 IIRC.

Initial, but not definitive, results suggest this solution is working better than the other suggestions documented here. I will update this post in a week or so to indicate whether this recipe is sufficient to gain a permanent and reliable solution.