# Git for Windows (not cygwin) svn clone: unable to remap to same address as parent

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-clone

My git installation under Win 8 is a standard setup (not full cygwin setup).
When I try to git svn clone, I get this error.
It repeats once a few seconds until I press Ctrl+D.

[image]

I've seen another thread here but it's all about Cygwin setup.
How would I fix my one?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5434930/68939

Answer (score 0):

So overall, I was following [this guide](http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/08/migrating-from-subversion-to-git-with.html).

The following commands fixed the error you mentioned, where git install path is wherever your Git is, and the path to the dlls is at the top of the error you mention (I got the second ddl after running the first command).

```
<git install path>\bin\rebase -b 0x64000000 <path to the dlls>libsvn_repos-1-0.dll

<git install path>\bin\rebase -b 0x64200000 <path to the dlls>libneon-25.dll
```

It might give you an error fetching after this, so do a manual git fetch again.

Note: Either use Ruby's command line or add it all to the PATH (this is in the linked document). Also, I found this commands while looking all over the internet but I cant remember the exact source. Most answers had to do with cygwin which I don't use.